How to specifiy networks in turffle contract
I am following a tutorial creating peer to peer payment on Polygon, and when using loadWallet I think we need to specify the network and in the code, the chainID of mumbai testnet is used.
const loadWallet = async () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      await window.ethereum.enable();
      const web3 = window.web3;
      var allAccounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      setAccount(allAccounts[0]);

      const paymentTokenData = PaymentToken.networks["80001"];
      if (paymentTokenData) {
        var paymentTokenInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(
          PaymentToken.abi,
          paymentTokenData.address
        );
        setPaymentToken(paymentTokenInstance);
        var bal = await paymentTokenInstance.methods
          .balanceOf(allAccounts[0])
          .call();
        setBalance(bal);
      } else {
        window.alert("TestNet not found");
      }
      setLoading(false);
    } else {
      window.alert("Non-Eth browser detected. Please consider using MetaMask.");
    }
  };

on the line const paymentTokenData = PaymentToken.networks["80001"];, I am getting the following error Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"80001"' can't be used to index type '{}'. Property '80001' does not exist on type '{}'.
PaymentToken.json
 "networks": {},
  "schemaVersion": "3.4.16",
  "updatedAt": "2024-07-05T12:57:25.623Z",

contract/PaymentToken.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract PaymentToken is ERC20 {
    address public owner;

    constructor() ERC20("Payment Token", "Pay") {
        owner = msg.sender;
        _mint(msg.sender, 100000 * 10**18);
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can mint");
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}

I believe we may need to include the network data in truffle contract to load the wallet properly.
Create a Peer to Peer payment dApp, Part 1
